# Async calls using HTTPClient vs Direct calling methods asynchronously using Tasks for a synchronous service

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library, dotnet-httpclient

I have a scenario in my existing application where on the click of a Save button a Javascript function is called. This javascript function internally makes 4-5 asynchronous calls to webservices.For some reasons we have big javascript files now with lot of business logic. Also we are facing performance issues in the application. To reduce the number of XHR calls we are making to the server, we thought of consolidating these calls on the server side and just make a single call from our Javascript.
On the server side we are using Async Await to make this calls asynchronous.So we have created a wrapper service with one method which now calls different service methods using SendAsync method exposed by HTTPClient.
Our underlying services are all synchronous and to achieve asynchronous functionality we used HTTPClient. We measured performance and it shows considerable gain.
But, one of our colleague pointed out that we will actually have an overhead of serialization and Deserialization as well as we are originating now other webservice calls from server which will ultimately run synchronously.So why not directly call the methods instead of new HTTP calls.
ow our methods are all synchronous and to make them asynchronous we will have to use Tasks which will again be overhead.
Both the approaches will be overhead but we see the making new HTTP requests using async await more inline with the microservices concept.
There is a debate and I would like to know other thoughts.

Comment: There is no debate: measure. Though unless you're creating hundreds of `Task`s, the overhead is likely going to be negligible.

Answer (score 0):

My two-cents:

The approach of aggregating the information on the server side is good.
From my point of view the use of HTTPClient internally on the server side is a solution only if you want to connect to a legacy service and you do not have the ability to integrate it directly. HTTPClient is simple to use and robust, but it's technically a lot more overhead than using a Task (think of error handling, serialisation, testing, network/socket-resources).

A Task is also nice, since it allows proper cancelation, which HTTPClient cannot achieve (HTTPClient can only close the socket, other end could still block resources).

On top of the general resource aspect, the use of Futures makes the Task a perfect match:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963556.aspx